# SQL update values from table in 1 database with values from another

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

I have two different Databases.  I need to update the names in the audit database from the info database where person_id = patient_num.

Database: audit

```
Table: person

person_id      name
    1          null
    2          null
    3          null
```

Database: info

```
Table: patient

patient_num      patient_name
    3            bob
    1            nancy
    2            sara
```

I've been looking at other posts but i am not having luck finding people referencing other databases.

Comment: Which RDBMS are we talking about here? Oracle? MySQL? SQL Server? ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `update` with `join`.  The syntax in MySQL is:

```
update audit.person pe join
       info.patient pa
       on pe.person_id = pa.patient_num
    set pe.name = pa.patient_name
    where pe.name is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE audit.person, info.patient
SET audit.person.name = info.patient.patient_name
WHERE audit.person.person_id = info.patient.patient_num
```

Comment: This is for SQL Server afaict.

Comment: @CamSonaris I have updated the query. Since mysql was not mentioned in the post (and not in tags) I assumed MS SQL.